# Download all pages under <domain-name>/*

Tags: downloads, offline, websites

Suppose I have a certain pages, e.g. `www.abc.def/ghi/a.html`, is there any command option to download all the pages under `www.abc.def./ghi` (i.e. `www.abc.def/ghi/a.html`, `www.abc.def/ghi/b.html`, ...)?

I've installed `httrack` and `webhttrack` but I don't know how to correctly use them.

Comment: `wget -r www.abc.def./ghi/`

Comment: wow, the famous `-r`! Btw, does it try to download ALL the links, even that under different domains? i.e. if the web pages contains link to `facebook` pages and so on, it follows the links and try to download these external pages also?

Comment: I never experienced that! - although that can be set as an option. Dunno which one tho.

Comment: well, as expected, it tried to download everything, even if it were only pages internal at the given domain (i.e. it tried to download `www.abc.def/*`). Sorry @blade19899, the solution doesn't work :(

Comment: possible [Unix.stackexchange question there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155423/possible-to-download-these-webpages-as-a-book/155646#155646)

Comment: @KasiyA thanks for the link. Btw, the most useful and complete answer is certainly the approved one http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155481/85082

Comment: Side question: Doesn't wget only download static pages, not dynamic pages? (Since OP is downloading static pages, wget should work.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution with `httrack` and is the simplest one.

```
httrack http://www.abc.def/ghi/ -O <output-folder>
```

the key is that, by default, `httrack` use the -D parameter:

> can only go down into subdirs

You can find more options typing `httrack --help`.
[Here](http://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html) is an useful link

Answer (score 3):

Try `wget`'s recursive download with restrictions:

```
wget -r --include-directories=ghi --no-parent www.abc.def
```

Comment: well, actually it works well, but at the same time it downloaded also stuffs like .pdfs or the robot.txt. Also, I like more the `httrack` options mainly because, if I try to download again the site at later point, it gives the opportunity to download only the updated stuffs (don't know if wget can have similar options)

Comment: For people who like online manuals: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/wget.1.html

Comment: @Bulrush if you use Ubuntu's manpages, please either link to a current one (say trusty and not something antique like hardy) or use the short url if it is unambiguous (like http://manpages.ubuntu.com/wget).

Comment: @muro, Thanks for the note, I didn't notice the manpage version. Will do.